# Visual studio + cmake confusion

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I am facing difficulty understanding cmake and I don't know if cmake is supposed to do what I need. Also I am using integrated cmake support in visual studio.

So the questions are:

**Can I use cmake to copy game assets and executable into build folder?**
I figured out that everything is built inside "buildRoot" specified in CMakeSettings, but what am I supposed to do when I need final output? (You are not supposed to copy and change everything manually, right?)

Final output should look like this:

```
/Build
->Output.exe
  /Sprites
  ->Image.png
  /Audio
```

**If it is possible to copy files like that, is it possible to set visual studio to run executable in our generated build folder instead of its "buildRoot" folder?** As I want to access assets using relative paths, running from buildRoot could be problematic.

**Can I set executable's icon, company name etc. using cmake?**

Comment: CMake should build everything, executable included, in **one** folder (which is typically placed as a sibling to your top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file. And you can run the executable from within Visual Studio after it builds. Why do you have two build folders `buildRoot` and `Build`?

Comment: I need to include graphics, sounds and etc. into same folder as executable. Also I would like to be able to generate final structured package to ship. (Without all that build junk).

Comment: CMake's [`install`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/install.html) commands and CPack can handle much of this. I suggest you read some about it, and check out some examples of its usage on GitHub, as it is highly configurable. Also, check out [WiX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/wix.html#cpack_gen:CPack%20WIX%20Generator) for customizing your installer, icons, etc.